# Windows 10 DHCP Client and RFC 3397 (a.k.a. DHCP option 119, Domain Search Option)

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, windows-10

Using **DHCP option 119, Domain Search Option** as documented in **RFC 3397** would make my life a lot easier. All the Linux-Machines on my network have supported this option for quite a while, but unfortunately I also have to take several Windows machines into account. Fortunately, they all run Windows 10, so there may yet be hope.

From what I gather Windows versions up to and including Windows 7 still did not comply to the RFC. I believe to have read that Windows 8 didn't either, but I can't find anything to confirm that right now.

But does **Windows 10's DHCP client** support **DHCP option 119**?

Comment: How would Active Directory work otherwise?

Comment: Not by default, but here is a way to enable it:   
https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rhepworth/2012/06/18/adding-dhcp-option-119-domain-search-list-to-windows-server-2008-r2/   
For reference, most organizations specify this using group policy.

Comment: @GregAskew The link you sent is for adding option 119 to a Windows DCHP *server*. I am already aware of this possibility, however, that is not what I need (The ISC DHCP server supports this without workarounds). What I am looking for is for Windows' DHCP *client* to use option 119. Group policies are unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
It wasn't supported back then, but it is supported now!

Since the April 2018 Update to Windows 10, its DHCP client has finally gained the ability to handle DHCP option 119 ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/dhcp/what-s-new-in-dhcp#new-dhcp-client-side-features-in-the-windows-10-april-2018-update)), only 16 years after its introduction.

So, years later, the topic came up again, and we've looked into it once more. It was still just as hard to find any information on this topic. This thread (still without an answer) was actually one of the best results our search brought up, so when we found the Microsoft announcement linked above, I decided to leave the answer here for anyone else who might end up here.